# How to compare current date with a stored date in a Substrate blockchain module?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I'm working with a `Substrate blockchain` and have a structure with a field named end_date. I'd like to check if the current date is greater than end_date within a Substrate runtime module, but I'm unsure how to implement this.

How can I retrieve the current date from the Substrate framework, and then compare it to end_date?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/how-to-store-date-on-storage

Comment: this post might also help https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-can-we-convert-the-timestamp-to-the-date-time-in-substrate-pallet/360#360